# Dagger 2 - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, dagger2

После проблемы с https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788772/android-error-the-realmclass-annotation-does-not-support-nested-classes/46788843#46788843

появилась другая проблема при компиляции проекта с dagger 2

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**clean & rebuild** и **remove .gradle & rebuild** не помогли.

Произошло после добавления бд Realm.

Есть предположения почему это произошло и как пофиксить?

Comment: Запустите билд с флагами специальными чтобы получить информацию об ошибке более подробную так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21674403/3212712